# How to know the unit of a number in swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to detect the type of number a user enters into a textField. For example

if the user enters **1000** The program should return **1Kcs**

if the user enters **12,000**, The program should return **12Kcs**

if the user enters **12,000,000** The program should return **12MCS**

How do I go about this in swift?

Thousands - **Kcs**
Hundreds - **Mcs**

Comment: Are they entering it with the commas?

Comment: show us the code that you have tried.

Comment: No they aren't @tktsubota

Comment: I tried getting the text from the text field the usual way, converted it to a double, thats it. Just thinking of a way to walk around with the rest of the implementation. Nothing fancy @johnelemans

Comment: What is the CS part? Is it supposed to be 12ThCS? How large does this scale, do you have the units for all of them?

Comment: Updated the question @tktsubota

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should to the job

```
extension Int {
    var unitFormatted: String {
        let positive = self < 0 ? -self : self
        switch positive {
        case 1_000_000..<Int.max: return "\(self / 1_000_000)MCS"
        case 1_000..<1_000_000: return "\(self / 1_000)Kcs"
        default: return "\(self)"
        }
    }
}
```

**Examples**

```
0.unitFormatted // "0"
1.unitFormatted // "1"
1000.unitFormatted // "1Kcs"
12000.unitFormatted // "12Kcs"
12000000.unitFormatted // "12MCS"
```

Answer (score 1):

Some variation of this to fit your needs should be fine:

```
var num = 12000000

switch num {
case 1000...999999:
    print(String(num/1000) + "Kcs")
case 1000000...999999999:
    print(String(num/1000000) + "Mcs")
default:
    print(num)
}
```